# Is it posssible to install MinGW-64 on a USB stick?

Tags: c++, usb, mingw, mingw-w64

My pc have a very low storage and i wanted to install the tools required to compile C++ code in my USB stick instead.

i tried to change the installation path in the MSYS setup but the progression bar froze to the "unpacking components" stage.
i specified the path in the environment variables after copying the MinGW folder in the USB but the cmd still doesn't recognize it.

is there a specific way to do it ?

Comment: There's little reason to use MSYS1 today. Consider [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). The main page has a list of restrictions on the installation location (notably, the filesystem should be NTFS), but it you format the USB stick to NTFS, it might work. Also it might help to install it elsewhere, then move the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standalone MinGW-w64 GCC build from https://winlibs.com/ and extract it to a USB stick.

Since it has no installer the supplied programs work wherever they are, so even if the USB drive changes drive letters.

Note: This answer assumes you just need the build tools and not the MSYS2 shell environment.